# Which CentOS ISO to use for my virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, iso-image

I have a physical server running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga). I would like to create a virtual machine (using VirtualBox) with a binary-compatible version of CentOS server as this RHEL server version, and have a few questions.

Given the following command outputs on the physical server (the RHEL server):

```
uname -a
========
Linux myrhelserv.org 2.6.18-229.el5 #1 SMP Tue Oct 26 18:54:44 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
==============
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
Release:    5.5
Codename:   Tikanga

cat /proc/version
=================
Linux version 2.6.18-229.el5 (mockbuild@ls20-bc2-13.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48))
#1 SMP Tue Oct 26 18:54:44 EDT 2010
```

Which CentOS ISO should I use from this page inside the [CentOS vault](http://vault.centos.org/5.5/isos/) for 5.5? Why?

Or should I use a different ISO entirely? If so, why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use which ever version meets the requirements for your project.  I would caution you from using a older linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound (+1) - So, given the output from the 3 linux commands, and given the fact that I want to mimic the physical server (`myrhelserv.org`) as close as possible, 32- or 64-bit? Which link on that page from the vault? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided,
I think you are running RHEL 5.5 on a 64-bit platform (as keywords like x86_64 and amd64 is found in your message).

Installing from a CentOS 5.5 64-bit image should give you the closest environment,
given that CentOS uses the same versioning from RHEL.